# loading while fetching firestore data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

While fetching some data from firestore, I am setting a loading state , but this state will return to true once again , I don't know why :

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true)
nprogress.start()
  const fetchGames=async()=>{
    const eventsFromDb = []
    const DB =await db.collection('event').get()
    DB.docs.forEach((item,index)=>{
      eventsFromDb[index]= item.data()
     })
     setEvents(eventsFromDb)
     setIsLoading(false)
     console.log(isLoading) // consoling this will return true after the progress is done(false)
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>
    {
      fetchGames()
      if(!isLoading)
      {
        nprogress.done()
      }

    }, [isLoading])
```

How can I fix this ? after it finished loading it starts over again

Comment: You deleted the other question but I already wrote a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12xgwnfv/

Comment: I really appreciate it !!! I am sorry I cannot accept it  as an answer here

Comment: No problem, I wouldn't have posted an answer anyway ;) Extracting hour/minute/etc from a string like that and turning the 12hr format into 24hr format are two separate questions that have definitely been solved before, as such your question wasn't suitable to remain on SO anyway

Answer (score 0):

React sets its state asynchronously so right after setting the state can still be true

Try it like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchGames()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoading) {
    nprogress.done()
  }
}, [isLoading])
```

Comment: how to fix this

Comment: That's only half true. Apart from the state update being asynchronous, the real issue here is that `fetchGames` is closed over the initial value of `isLoading` (which is `true`). So even if you were to delay the `console.log` (with setTimeout or whatever), it would still log `true`.

Comment: indeed any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue , by just ordering the code , since I was setting the Loading after I store the data in an array   :

```
const fetchGames=async()=>{
    const eventsFromDb = []
    const DB =await db.collection('event').get()
    DB.docs.forEach((item,index)=>{
      eventsFromDb[index]= item.data()
     })
     setIsLoading(false) // This will be replaced above the setEvents
     setEvents(eventsFromDb)
   
     console.log(isLoading) // 
    }
```